# Google Sheets value on chart off from source by very small fraction

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to figure out why Google Sheets chart is off from the source data by a small fraction. My sheet has 7 rows of data and a sum row. All data only has 2 decimal points and the sum obviously has 2 decimal points. Yet when plotted, the sum is off as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

The callout on the chart is pulling its data from cell C12. Formula for C12 is just SUM(C4:C10). I expanded the decimal places in C12 to show that nothing was hidden/rounded/truncated. Trying to understand why this is happening and how to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce it, but this looks like a well-known (at least among programmers) [peculiarity in floating point arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/4751173). You can see in the graph that the internal representation of the number is different from what you'd expect.

The only solution I see is to decrease the number of decimals in C1, e.g. with this button in the toolbar:

[image]